# How to pass a json as an entry parameter of a function

Tags: python, json, string, dictionary

I need to pass a json object as an entry parameter to my function. This function is prepared to read the json and extract the needed data.

This is the function:

```
def leerJSON(carrito):
    data = json.loads(carrito)
    
    lista_nombres_y_usuarios = []
    for i in range(1):
        #data = json.loads(data1)
        user = data[i]
        nombre = user['name'] 
        username = user['username']
        email = user['email']
        lista_nombres_y_usuarios.append([nombre, username])

    return(nombre, username, email, array)
```

And this is the script from witch i call the function `leerJSON()`:

```
carrito = '''{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
}'''
carritojson= json.dumps(carrito, indent = 4) # Conversión a json
[name, username, email, array] = leerJSON(carritojson)
print(name)
print(username)
print(email)
print(array)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/idein/Escritorio/Factura/prueba.py", line 12, in <module>
    [name, username, email, array] = leerJSON(carritojson)
  File "/home/idein/Escritorio/Factura/funcionLecturaJSON.py", line 36, in leerJSON
    nombre = user['name'] 
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

As you can see it says that the object does not have text as an attribute and this is because carrito is a dictionary and not a json. How could i convert it? because I have read that with json.dumps() you could convert but it says is an string and no more a dictionary.

Comment: what is leerJSON?

Comment: @funnydman i just edited the question an added what it is. Is the function i use to read the json.

Comment: The code you've shown is different than the code shown in the exception traceback. Make sure you've saved your code and that you're running the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues in your code :

1. The variable `carrito` is defined as a `str`, so `json.loads` will return a `str`. Define it as a `dict` so that `json.loads` returns a `dict`.
2. The variable `carrito` is not a list so `user = data[i]` will not work. I think you tried to create `carrito` as a `list` of `dict`.
3. `array` is not defined in `leerJSON`. I think you tried to return `lista_nombres_y_usuarios`